# What is the C64 disk drive "Jiffy" protocol?

Tags: commodore-64, floppy-drive

There seems to be something called the "Jiffy protocol" used for some fast load systems. I know of the [JiffyDOS](http://www.go4retro.com/products/jiffydos/) product, which seems to require replacing ROMs in both the C64 and the drive, but it seems that other programs and devices (such as [SD2IEC](https://www.thefuturewas8bit.com/index.php/sd2iec-info)'s GPL'd firmware and [SDOS V1.1](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=176967)) also support this.

Is this protocol documented anywhere? How does it work? What libraries, software and hardware (both real and emulated) support faster disk transfers using this?

Comment: Did you find any documentation?  I am also interested in this.

Answer (score 6):

This is an incomplete answer.

https://www.pagetable.com/?p=1018 references an as-yet-unwritten article about JiffyDOS:

> JiffyDOS, a 3rd party ROM patch for computers and drives, replaces layer 2 byte transmission of Standard Serial by using the clock and data lines in a more efficient way. Bus arbitration is unchanged. The controller detects a device’s JiffyDOS support and can fall back to the Standard Serial protocol.

http://www.baltissen.org/newhtm/sourcecodes.htm includes a link to JiffyDOS source, apparently licensed from the original author (Mark Fellows) to Jim Brain (via http://www.go4retro.com/products/jiffydos/) and then to this page, though it should be noted the page explicitly says you should have a JiffyDOS license to use the code: http://www.baltissen.org/files/C64-kerJD.a65

Comment: Incomplete, but still very helpful. Especially that link to Baltissen's source code page!